# Shortest path maze solving algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, maze

I have this method that solves the first possible path in a 2D maze matrix (works fine)

```
    public boolean findFirstPath() {
        boolean found = false;
        path = new ArrayList<Coordinate>(); // restarts the path in case the algorithm has been solved previously
        Coordinate coor = new Coordinate();
        coor.i = startI; coor.j = startJ; coor.direction = 0; // instance of the first Coordinate object
        path.add(coor); // the first coordinate is added to the path
        
        while (!found && path.size() > 0) {
            path.get(path.size()-1).direction++; // accesses the last element and increments the direction by 1
            if (path.get(path.size()-1).direction <= 4) {
                Coordinate coor_next = setNextCell(path.get(path.size()-1)); // we assign the last element of the path
                if (isValidSpot(coor_next)) {
                    path.add(coor_next); // add to the path the valid cell
                    if (coor_next.i == endI && coor_next.j == endJ) { // if it reaches the end
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
            } else { // if it has checked all 4 directions go back
                path.remove(path.size()-1); // deletes the last position in backtracking
            }
        }   
        return found;
    }
```

I need to make modifications to find the shortest possible path and I can't find an optimal solution, I've tried something like this:

```
    public boolean findShortestPath() {
        boolean found = false;
        int steps = 0;
        path = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
        ArrayList<Coordinate> shortest = new ArrayList<Coordinate>(); // arrayList where the shortest path will be stored
        Coordinate coor = new Coordinate();
        coor.i = startI; coor.j = startJ; coor.direction = 0;
        path.add(coor);
        
        while (!found && path.size() > 0) {
            path.get(path.size()-1).direction++;
            if (path.get(path.size()-1).direction <= 4) {
                Coordinate coor_next = setNextCell(path.get(path.size()-1));
                if (isValidSpot(coor_next)) {
                    steps++;
                    if (steps < path.size()) {
                        shortest.add(path.get(path.size()-1));
                    } else {
                        path.add(coor_next);
                    }
                    if (coor_next.i == endI && coor_next.j == endJ) {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                path.remove(path.size()-1);
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
```

but it does not even enter the `if (steps < path.size())` comprobation, any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something like a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)?

Comment: Nope, I find it difficult to implement it with the direction attribute of the Coordinate object, I know that by making a small modification in my code I don't have to rewrite the algorithm but right now my mind is a real labyrinth itself.

Comment: A heuristically short-enough path, or mathematical geodesic? Generally, [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) is pretty good.

Comment: I think you should work out that Breadth First search, it's the only way.  Trying to "wing it" with algorithm's is generally a bad idea.  The algorithms that everybody uses are popular for a reason: they work and are almost always optimal if you choose the right one.  I've lots of even experienced programmers try to invent their own ideas and fail spectacularly.  ([Ariane rocket disaster anyone?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_flight_V88) )